# How to grab list of custom slack slash commands using Python?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

Currently what is on my mind is 2 methods:

1) Go to the slash command app webpage and scrape the HTML

2) Use one of the slack API commands to query for it

Currently where I am stuck:

1) The HTML codes produced when I am logged on using Chrome vs when I authenticate using tester token via Python is different. Hence, when I use Python (requests and lxml libraries), the resulting HTML codes do not contain the slash command details.

2) I have navigated through the Slack API commands, but it mostly revolves around sending messages, bots, etc. I couldn't find an API command that is able to retrieve the slash commands list and the details (e.g. description, permissions, etc.)

Comment: Just two thoughts. 1) Have you tried adding a user agent header to your request? This sometimes helps in tricking the API in thinking you are a browser. 2) You could go with a selenium based approach to get the proper data from scraping.

Comment: Thanks @Imre_G, was trying to do a scheduled auto data extraction though... maybe I can try the header thing you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have now found an undocumented API method that returns the list of all slash commands (build-in and custom) from a workspace.

Syntax: `https://slack.com/api/commands.list?token=YOUR-TOKEN`

Note that you need a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) for this method to work.

You can find a full documentation of this method [here](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/commands.list.md).